# Accessing a given child of a ControlTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, code-behind

I have this ControlTemplate that contains stuff (gradients in this case) that I want to be able to access programmatically and after hours of trial and error I feel that it's finally time to turn to you for assistance, StackOverflow.

The template generates a flower, and I didn't know what to use, so I just picked the Thumb-element, since I've used that before in a similar manner. If you can think of anything else that would be better suited, please let me know.

Anyways, this is the beginning of my ControlTemplate, from the XAML-file:

```xaml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="cherryFlowerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Viewbox Width="119.560" Height="114.268" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
                            <Canvas Width="119.560" Height="114.268">
                                <Canvas>
                                    <!-- Layer 1/<Path> -->
                                    <Path Data="... (removed to save space) ...">
                                        <Path.Fill>
                                            <RadialGradientBrush x:Name="cherryFlowerColorGradient" MappingMode="Absolute" GradientOrigin="593.380,333.416" Center="593.380,333.416" RadiusX="36.460" RadiusY="36.460">
                                                <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                                    <!-- Flower color -->
                                                    <GradientStop x:Name="cherryFlowerColorGradientOuterColor" Offset="0.15" Color="#ffd6e062"/>
```

And here's what I'm doing in C#:

```cs
Thumb flower = new Thumb();
flower.Template = TryFindResource("cherryFlowerStyle") as ControlTemplate;
GradientStop grStop = (GradientStop)flower.Template.FindName("cherryFlowerColorGradientOuterColor", flower);
                        Console.WriteLine("gradient: " +grStop);
```

Creating a new Thumb and applying the template works (it's drawn as a flower on the canvas).
Trying to access the gradients inside the template, however, does not work. I hope there's a good solution to this, or else I have to do it the ugly way; create a flower off-screen (in XAML) and reference that in the code-behind, because that works :/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, because the Gradient is not a child of your template, its the value of the property of a child of your template. So you can access the `Path` by name, and modify its `Fill` value. But remember, the Gradient might be frozen.
Why not use binding and the DataContext for that? Or yet better, use dependency properties to modify the colors directly and just use TemplateBinding. It would be a much much better way to handle that, with less work. Also the Thumb element is used for moving elements and it encapsulates the mouse handling for that, if you don't need that the `Control` element would be a better base class. If you want performance, `Visual` or `ContainerVisual` would be much better, but also very limited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you mean I can use this thing "dependency properties" to modify given elements in my ControlTemplate? Where do I write this code, do I make a new .cs file for it or where does it go?

Btw, I tried to access the Path-element, but it didn't work :/ Here's what I tried with:

System.Windows.Shapes.Path path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)flower.Template.FindName("pathName123", flower);

Comment: It didn't worked is never a good answer. Dependency properties are one of the corner stones of WPF. I would advise you to get more basic knowledge of WPF. The short answer; DepProps are used for bindings, animations and are part of a control, in fact you already used a lot of depprops, every property you set a value to in xaml, is almost always a dependency property. And yes depprops can be accessed in the code behind file of a [custom control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx), and can be bound via [TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx)

Comment: Okay, I'll have to study this topic a bit more I guess. Thanks for the help.